# this.setState() not a function after successful API call method

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx, fetch-api

This question has come up quite a few times on here, I know, but none of the solutions have worked for me. So, I'm making a call to the iTunes API with a `fetch` request, based on user input in a React app. The initial call/submit works just fine. However, when I try to do a second search, I get a `this.setState is not a function` error as soon as I type in the input box. I've tried binding `this` in all the methods and in all the ways one can, but no success in getting it to work. Any ideas?

```
class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            artist: null,
            albums: []
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.getSearchResults = this.getSearchResults.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ query: event.target.value });
    }

    getSearchResults() {
        console.log('query!!! ' + this.state.query);
        const URL_TEMPLATE = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=album&limit=25&term={query}";
        let url = URL_TEMPLATE.replace('{query}', this.state.query);
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                let data = response.json();
                return data;
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data.results);
                this.setState ({
                    albums: data.results
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        this.setState({ query: '' });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <hr />
                <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <input type="text"
                            value={this.state.query}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            className="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." />
                        <span className="input-group-btn">
                            <button
                                onClick={() => this.getSearchResults()}
                                className="btn btn-default" type="button">Go
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div>
                    Albums: {this.state.albums}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }}
```

**edit:** I should mention that it gives me the error on the `handleChange()` method, since that's what deals with the input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete working code

```js
import React from 'react';
class TestJS extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            query: '',
            artist: null,
            albums: []
        };
        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.getSearchResults = this.getSearchResults.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({ query: event.target.value });
    }

    getSearchResults() {
        console.log('query!!! ' + this.state.query);
        const URL_TEMPLATE = "https://itunes.apple.com/search?entity=album&limit=25&term={query}";
        let url = URL_TEMPLATE.replace('{query}', this.state.query);
        fetch(url)
            .then((response) => {
                let data = response.json();
                return data;
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data.results);
                this.setState({
                    albums: data.results
                });
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
            });

        this.setState({ query: '' });
    }

    render() {
        let plus5 = [];
        if(!!this.state.albums && this.state.albums.length > 0){
            this.state.albums.map((val, i, arr) => {
                plus5.push(<div key={i}>{val.artistId}</div>);
            });
        }
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <hr />
                <div className="col-lg-6">
                    <div className="input-group">
                        <input type="text"
                               value={this.state.query}
                               onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
                               className="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." />
                        <span className="input-group-btn">
                            <button
                                onClick={() => this.getSearchResults()}
                                className="btn btn-default" type="button">Go
                            </button>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div>
                    {plus5}
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default TestJS;
```

I've just rendered artistId. You can render anything you want

Thanks!

Comment: @HarshMakadia tell us what you changed? Curious to know how you fixed it.

Comment: @Raaj Nadar - there was one setState syntax issue also you cannot directly render the response received from the API since it is in array format. You have to iterate over it and then push into the UI.

Comment: Oh nice, Maybe that will be helpful for me in future

Answer (score 1):

Does arrow function work?

```
<input type="text"
       value={this.state.query}
       onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
       className="form-control" placeholder="Search for..." />
```

And you cannot call `setState()` like this:

```
this.setState = {
   albums: data.results
};
```

please change to :

```
this.setState({
   albums: data.results
});
```

Comment: oops, typo on that setState(). thanks for the catch. also, arrow function doesn't work

Comment: because this.setState became {albums: data.results} after the function of getSearchResults, then you call this.setState in handleChange again, of course this.setState is not a function.

Answer (score 0):

I think since you are inside the closure, `this` is not available inside

```
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data.results);
       this.setState = {
       albums: data.results
    };
})
```

Try assigning `let that = this` outside and before the `fetch` call.

And then

```
.then((data) => {
    console.log(data.results);
    that.setState = {
       albums: data.results
    };
})
```

Comment: i tried this for both handleChange and getSearchResults, still didn't work either way.